# need help with php loop logic

Tags: php, loops

This code works perfectly except that it doesn't print the last 2 rows of my csv file:

This is the file:

```
603629,0,ATLV0008,"Vendor1",1942.60,11/04/2010,1942.60,9/1-9/30/10,EFT-JP
603627,2,ATLV0008,"Vendor1",1242.40,11/04/2010,1242.40,7/1-7/31/10,EFT-JP
600023,0,FLD4V0003,"Vendor2",1950.00,06/15/2010,1950.00,6/14/10 Request,EFT-JP
600024,0,FLD4V0003,"Vendor2",1800.00,06/15/2010,1800.00,6/14/10 Request,EFT-JP
603631,0,ATLV5066,"Vendor2",1000.00,11/09/2010,1000.00,11/4/10 Check Request,PM2
603647,0,ATLV5027,"DVendor3",2799.80,11/15/2010,2799.80,10/1-10/31/10 Bishop,PM2
603642,5,ATLV5027,"Vendor3",482.40,11/15/2010,482.40,10/1-10/18/10 Allen,PM2
603653,0,ATLV0403,"Vendor4",931.21,11/17/2010,931.21,9/1-9/30/10,EFT-JP
603661,0,ATLV0105,"Vendor5",26.75,11/19/2010,26.75,093139,PM2
603660,1,ATLV0105,"Vendor5",5.35,11/19/2010,5.35,093472,PM2
```

Here is the code: (It needs to display the sum of 2 rows with the same vendor before the actual rows)

```
if (($handle = fopen('upload/ATLANTA.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($row_array = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))) { 
    foreach ($row_array as $key => $val) {
        $row_array[$key] = trim(str_replace('"', '', $val));
        ob_flush();
        }
    $complete[] = $row_array;
    ob_flush();
    }
}
flush();

$prevVendor = '';
$sum = 0;
$venData = '';

    if (isset($complete)) {

        foreach ($complete as $key => $val) {
            $venData .= "<br/>";   
            $currVendor = $complete[$key][3];   

            if ($currVendor != $prevVendor){

                    if ($prevVendor != NULL){
                        print "<br/>";
                        print $sum . "<br/>";
                        print $venData;
                        $sum = 0; $venData = '';
                    }
                }   

        foreach ($val as $ikey => $ival){
            if ($ikey != 1){
                $venData .= $ival . '&nbsp';
                $prevVendor = $val[3];
                }
        }  

         if ($currVendor == $prevVendor){
                $sum += $complete[$key][6];
            }    
    }
```

}

Comment: Please try to improve your rate of acceptance on your other questions.

Comment: if you ask a question, and someone answers it correctly, mark it so

Comment: (click the tick by the most helpful post in your previous questions)

Comment: I Recommend Better Indention And Trying To Build A Rational Loop That Iterate Once Over the csv file data

Comment: Could there be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem but if you want to get (and save it wherever you want) the sum of each vendors, you should do something like this :

```
$prevVendor = null;
$venData = '';
$sums = array();

if (isset($complete) && is_array($complete)) {
    $lim = count($complete);
    for ($key=0;$key<$lim;++$key) { // no need foreach for simple array
        $venData .= "<br/>";   
        $currVendor = $complete[$key][3];   

        if ($currVendor != $prevVendor){

            if ($prevVendor != null){
                print "<br/>";
                print $venData;

            }

            $venData = '';
            $prevVendor = $currVendor;
            $sums[$currVendor] = 0; // set the counter to 0

        }   

        foreach ($complete[$key] as $ikey => $ival){
            if ($ikey != 1){
                $venData .= $ival . '&nbsp;'; // is useful for you I guess
            }
        }

        $sums[$currVendor] += $complete[$key][6]; // add amounts

    }
}

if ($prevVendor != null){ // you need to do this to display the last record
    print "<br/>";
    print $venData;

}
var_export($sums); // check results
```

This can be some syntax errors ...

Comment: The sum calculation is working fine, the problem is that the last two lines of the file do not get printed, since the printing happens at the beginning and the looping happens at the end.  The reason I have to keep it that way is because I need the sum calculation to happen before the printing.

Comment: I still don't get it ... Add this after the loop? : 
if ($prevVendor != NULL){
 print $sum . "<br/>";
}

Comment: Add this after the loop : if ($prevVendor != null){
                print "<br/>";
                print $venData;

            }